# Are there AngularJS data update callbacks? How do I manually update page when data changes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I went through the AngularJS tutorial and it's pretty neat. I've also dipped into Backbone and Ember.js (though not totally familiar with either) but I've heard lots of praise over AngularJS and I want to see if it will work for me.

I have a site that focuses around a large Google map (think of something like Padmapper.com). Over 2,000 cars that are currently loaded via JSON after page load, and that JSON takes 1-2 seconds to arrive. The map is then populated with markers based on car location. I have a filter form with which the user can filter the cars based on many different attributes (let's just say color, amount of gas, etc.) Currently submitting this filter form queries the back end with the filters which then returns the filtered cars. This is a huge waste of time.

I'd like to load all the items on initialization, then use the front end to filter as they change the values. In the AngularJS tutorial, items appear and disappear as I type in the filter box. Pretty cool. But how do I handle map markers? How can I define a callback function to manually update the map markers once they come in? Do I need to use custom directives somehow? (Still not totally sure what these do...)

I can think of a solution in jQuery, i.e. have an unordered list of the cars, watch it for changes, and hide/show markers as necessary. But I'm trying to move away from jQuery. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a directive, you could $watch for a change on your list of cars and reapply the markers on your map. I am not familiar with Google Maps programming, but here's an attempt to illustrate what I talking about: http://plnkr.co/edit/d8Dn6epgnQ9UvWrMDAk8?p=preview

**EDIT**:

I found a great way of keeping track of the filtered results:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in (filteredcars = (cars | filter: query))">
```

This create on the fly the variable filteredcars and no need to bind a change event on the input query!

So to recap:

1) You can $watch data for change. But don't forget the 3rd parameter to tell it is an array.

```
scope.$watch('myvar', function(newval, oldval) {...}, true);
```

2) You can create a variable on the fly containing the filtered results of an expression coming from an ng-repeat.

3) Don't forget to empty the map element before you append child elements, otherwise, the filtered elements won't appear to be working.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your answer and the demo. I tried placing `<input ng-model="query">` in the page and filtering the car list by that, but the "map" area does not change. I suppose `$watch` here is watching the whole cars object, not the filtering of cars. How would I be able to incorporate those filters?

Comment: I'll try something and let you know.

Comment: Would it be possible to hold the filtered car object in the scope, like `$scope.filteredCars`? Like any changes to the filter form -> re-assign filteredCars. Then the map watches filteredCars and handles changes as necessary? Maybe this is a roundabout way that can be handled more easily. Thanks a bunch for looking into this

Comment: I updated the plunker so you can add new cars and it is getting $watch correctly. I had forgot to put the 3rd parameter to $watch when you use an array variable! As for your idea, i think it would work fine!

Comment: I also modified the directive so you can pass within the attribute the name of the property to $watch, so you can change between "cars" and "filteredcars" and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, I'm starting to see it now. I think there is one piece missing, how to I update filteredcars when the query input is updated?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to empty the map before redrawing the elements on it (display issue). I updated the plunker with a query input which triggers an onchange event and apply a the filter according to the query (ie: it search for the input on any field on the cars array).

Comment: Looks awesome! That demo was really helpful. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @jpmorin Thanks awesome trick there with the fly variable.
Only thing that's missing there is `$watchCollection` in-place `$watch`