# Footable along with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, footable

I m trying to use footable(http://themergency.com/footable-demo/responsive-container.htm) along with angular.js.

[image]

As the window size is reduced, Column 3, 4, 5 are only shown when plus sign is clicked.

Angular.js provides filtering capabilities, so when I put some search string like below:

[image]

Rows in the table are filtered.

Now the problem is when I try to remove this search string as below:

[image]

all the rows are again show, but the UI is distorted.

I tried to get a callback in angular.js using

```
$scope.$watch('searchStringID', function() {
$('#tableId').trigger('footable_initialize');
}
```

but did not work, if anybody can suggested how to address this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: WOuld suggest either using an angular grid and your own media queries to hide columns, or use footable filtering/sorting

Answer (score 12):

To add to [Daniel Stucki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21057869/657661), instead of adding each individual row each time `ng-repeat` executes, you can wait until ng-repeat is finished and then initialize FooTable on the parent table itself:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return function(scope, element){
    var footableTable = element.parents('table');

    if( !scope.$last ) {
      return false;
    }

    if (! footableTable.hasClass('footable-loaded')) {
      footableTable.footable();
    }
  };
})
```

This scales much better on tables with many rows.

Note `element` is automatically a [jQlite/jQuery object](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), so there is no longer a need to wrap it in `$()` syntax.

**Update**

One of the advantages of AngularJS is the two-way data binding. To keep FooTable data in sync with the latest data, you can do something like this:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return function(scope, element){
    var footableTable = element.parents('table');


    if( !scope.$last ) {
        return false;
    }

    scope.$evalAsync(function(){

        if (! footableTable.hasClass('footable-loaded')) {
            footableTable.footable();
        }

        footableTable.trigger('footable_initialized');
        footableTable.trigger('footable_resize');
        footableTable.data('footable').redraw();

    });
  };
})
```

The `scope.$evalAsync` wrapper executes once the DOM is ready but before it is displayed, preventing data flickering. The additional `trigger` and `redraw` method forces the initialized FooTable instance to update when the data changes.

This directive preserves the user experience - any FooTable sorting, filtering, or pagination stays remains in place - while loading data seamlessly whenever it is updated.

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled upon the same question. After finally writing an own solution to get a table with hidden columns, I managed to solve your problem (assuming your using ng-repeat to build your table).

html:

```
<div ng-init="friends =     [{name:'data11', phone:'data12'},
                         {name:'data21', phone:'data22'},
                         {name:'data31', phone:'data32'},
                         {name:'data41', phone:'data42'},
                         {name:'data51', phone:'data52'}]"></div>

Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<table id="searchTextResults" class="footable">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th><th data-hide="phone">Column3</th><th data-hide='phone'>Column4</th><th data-hide='phone'>Column5</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText" my-directive>
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return function(scope, element)
  {

    if(scope.$last && !$('.footable').hasClass('footable-loaded')) {
            $('.footable').footable();
    }

    var footableObject = $('.footable').data('footable');
    if (footableObject  !== undefined) {
            footableObject.appendRow($(element));
    }

  };})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone happens to stumble across this in the future, there's an angular directive available for FooTable here: https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable.

Comment: Unfortunately, that directive does not work with FooTable v3, only FooTable v2.